# Understanding basic notions on copulas

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, independence, correlation

Consider two random variables $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ with marginal cdf respectively $F_1, F_2$ and joint cdf $F$.

Is it true that for any $F, F_1, F_2$ we can write
$$
F(\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)=C(F_1(\epsilon_1), F_2(\epsilon_2); \rho)
$$
where $C$ is a bivariate copula function with parameter $\rho$ controlling for the correlation between the two random variables?

If not, could you provide a counter-example?

Comment: By Sklar's theorem you do not need the $\rho$ as there exist a unique $C$ such that $F(\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2) = C(F_1(\varepsilon_1),F_2(\varepsilon_2))$ (if the marginals are cont.)

Comment: The Pearson and Spearman correlation coefficients both only exist when the marginals have finite second moments.